# How to bind Kendo Grid Inside Kendo Drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to bind **kendo-UI Grid inside kendo-UI drop down**.

There is an option for Kendo treeview but not for kendo grid.

please provide any solution if any.

thanks.

Comment: Please share any relevant reference links that you have visited and might be helpful in achieving this

Comment: A grid inside a dropdown? Even a treeview would be wierd, I would like to see it, can you show us?

Comment: @sanjay, As per my knowledge we can't display grid inside dropdown. But you can display data in tabular format. for reference please check http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx To display data in tabular format you can use template in kendo ui dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

After some googling I got one solution may be useful to some one.
Please go to following link.

thanks.

[Click to See Solution](http://aspnet.wikidot.com/page:kendoui-ext-api-dropdowngrid)